# I am trying to create and spawn multiple instance of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I am getting an thread exception at planes.append(plane). I don't know what seems to be the problem.
click on the link for code page
[error at planes.append(plane)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew21N.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cxA2.png

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Don't add images of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your Plane class is this:

```
class Plane: SKSpriteNode {}
```

Listen. You are creating the wrong class.
You need to create a Plane class, and not a SKSpriteNode class. They are different.

Initialize the plane class like this:

```
var plane = Plane(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
```

Problem solved :)

Comment: yes my Plane class is 
Class Plane: SKSpriteNode{}
and i am new to swift so still learning.
if I don't create Plane class with SKSpriteNode then I have other attribute which i want each plane to have. and I also want physical body attach to it.

Comment: This will solve your crash. Mark it as right answer when you test it :)

Comment: Another Question?
so do i have to put each plane into self.addChild() everytime in frame or I only do that once.

Comment: If you want to have more planes, you gotta call addChild for each of them. Yeah :)